# Using Swing, I want to draw a couple of points

Tags: java, swing, drawing, 2d

...  in an image and do some calculation on their [x y] coordinates.

My first idea was to use an image as the background of a JPanel and then register the points, but I'm not sure there will be a way to mark these on the JPanel. There is also the Drawing library, which I'm unfamiliar with, but I'm not sure if I can combine these with Swing.

Can you name me the packages/classes I can use in order to do the task? References of code that already does it are also welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is three-fold:

1. There needs to be a way to display a background image.
2. One must be able to find the point at which the mouse was clicked.
3. There must be a way to draw the point on the panel.

One way to accomplish the above points would be to subclass a [`JPanel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) and provide those functionalities.

**1. Display a background image in a panel.**

Firstly, as a `JPanel` does not have a way of displaying a background image by default, there must be a way to hold an image in the `JPanel`, and then draw that on the panel itself, which can be performed via the [`paintComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)) method.

One way to accomplish this is to have a field in the class which holds on to an `Image` to draw:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    // Background image. Initialize appropriately.
    Image backgroundImage;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Draw background image each time the panel is repainted.
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

The [`Graphics`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object in `paintComponent` is associated with the `MyPanel` and can be used to perform graphics operations.

**2. Finding the point at which the mouse was clicked.**

Secondly, in order to retrieve the point at which the mouse was clicked, one could assign a [`MouseListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to the `MyPanel`. In the following example, an anonymous inner class extending the [`MouseAdapter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) is used to minimize writing extra code:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    // Background image. Initialize appropriately.
    Image backgroundImage;

    public MyPanel() {
         // Add a MouseListener which processes mouse clicks.
         this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                 // Process mouse-click.
             }
         })
    }

    // paintComponents method here.
}
```

Processing that needs to be performed when the mouse is clicked can be included in the `mouseClicked` method.

**3. How to draw a point on the panel.**

Thirdly, in order to find one point at which the mouse was clicked, one can obtain it from the [`MouseEvent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) object that was passed in from the [`mouseClicked`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html#mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)) method:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    // Background image. Initialize appropriately.
    Image backgroundImage;
    Point pointClicked;

    public MyPanel() {
         // Add a MouseListener which processes mouse clicks.
         this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                 // Retrieve the point at which the mouse was clicked.
                 pointClicked = e.getPoint();

                 // Repaint the panel.
                 this.repaint();
             }
         })
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Draw background image each time the panel is repainted.
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);

        // Draw a little square at where the mouse was clicked.
        g.fillRect(pointClicked.x, pointClicked.y, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Although the above code is not tested, it should be a starting point.

For example, if multiple points needs to be drawing, perhaps having a `List<Point>` to hold the points, and drawing each [`Point`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) in the `paintComponents` method could be done.

If additional processing needs to be performed when the mouse is clicked, additional code can be added to the `mouseClicked` method.

Additional resources:

- [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/)
- [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

*Thank you to zedoo for pointing out in the comments that making a call to `super.paintComponent` should be performed when overriding the `paintComponent` method.*

Comment: When overwriting paintComponent, you should make sure that the hole component gets painted, either by calling super.paintComponent() or by filling it with a rectangle of its size (i guess the two options are pretty equal for JPanels)

Answer (score 1):

Subclass a JPanel and override the method paintComponent:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

}
```

In the method you can use methods of the Graphics object passed to it. This method will be invoked every time there is a need to redraw the panel, so you need to store your points in an array and then read and draw each of them in your paintComponent.

Answer (score 1):

You may also find this useful, in case you want a heavyweight component (AWT), [this](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/canvas.html) tutorial explains how to extend the Canvas class to draw stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The [Background Panel](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=background-panel) gives a couple of suggestion on how to display a background image depending on your requirements.

[Custom Painting Approaches](http://www.camick.com/java/blog.html?name=custom-painting-approaches) then gives some ideas of how to do custom painting if you need to add custom points to the image.